# Elasticsearch license.expired.feature security status 403

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am using below code

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("https://10.8.173.179:9200"));
                    settings.BasicAuthentication("elastic", "password"); 
                    settings.ServerCertificateValidationCallback(CertificateValidations.AllowAll);
                    var lowlevelClient = new ElasticLowLevelClient(settings);
                    var health = lowlevelClient.Cluster.Health<StringResponse>().DebugInformation;
```

Getting  :
"security","suppressed":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"current license is non-compliant for [security]","license.expired.feature":"security"}]},"status":403}

Comment: your license expired, it says clearly

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may have been using a trial license. You can check which license you are running with by using the [Get License API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/get-license.html)

```
var client = new ElasticLowLevelClient();

var getLicenseResponse = client.License.Get<StringResponse>();
```

which will issue the request

```
GET http://localhost:9200/_license
```

If the `"type"` is `"trial"` in the returned response, you are using a trial license.

You can revert to using a free basic license. If you're running

- a 6.x version greater or equal to 6.8.0
- a 7.x version greater or equal to 7.1.0

[Core security features such as TLS, basic and native realm and role-based access control can be used with the basic license.](https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free).

To start the basic license, you can use the [Start Basic License API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/start-basic.html)

```
var startBasicResponse = client.License.StartBasic<StringResponse>();
```

which sends a request to

```
POST http://localhost:9200/_license/start_basic
```

**NOTE** As per the API documentation, you **must** submit the API request with the `acknowledge` parameter set to `"true"` for the changes to take effect; you can submit the API call first without setting this parameter, to understand what changes it makes it terms of access to features.

Answer (score 1):

your license is expired. you used xpack for your peoject. trial version is just 30 day

you can use basic authenticate for free.

fallow this page for more information:

[enter link description here](https://www.zdnet.com/article/some-elasticsearch-security-features-are-now-free-for-everyone/)

[https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free](https://www.zdnet.com/article/some-elasticsearch-security-features-are-now-free-for-everyone/)